# How to map collection to collection container with Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm having some trouble trying to map these two classes (Control -> ControlVM)

```
    public class Control
    {
        public IEnumerable<FieldType> Fields { get; set; }

        public class FieldType
        {
            //Some properties
        }
    }


    public class ControlVM
    {
        public FieldList Fields { get; set; }

        public class FieldList
        {
            public IEnumerable<FieldType> Items { get; set; }
        }

        public class FieldType
        {
            //Properties I'd like to map from the original
        }
    }
```

I tried with `opt.ResolveUsing(src => new { Items = src.Fields })` but apparently AutoMapper cannot resolve the anonymous type. Also tried extending `ValueResolver`, but didn't work either.

**NOTE:** This VM is later used in a WebApi, and JSON.NET needs a wrapper around the collection to properly deserialize it. So removing the wrapper is not a solution.

**NOTE2:** I'm also doing `Mapper.CreateMap<Control.FieldType, ControlVM.FieldType>()`, so the problem isn't there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Control.FieldType, ControlVM.FieldType>();

// Map between IEnumerable<Control.FieldType> and ControlVM.FieldList:
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Control.FieldType>, ControlVM.FieldList>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Items, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

Mapper.CreateMap<Control, ControlVM>();
```

*Update*: Here's how to map the other way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ControlVM.FieldType, Control.FieldType>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ControlVM, Control>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Fields, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Fields.Items));
```

Comment: Great! it also works without the last `CreateMap` (AutoMapper always tries to map properties with the same name)

Comment: How would you perform the inverse mapping? (ControlVM.FieldList -> IEnumerable<Control.FieldType>). AutoMapper is throwing "AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type."

Comment: @faloi: I'll take a look and see what I can come up with

Comment: @faloi: Hmm, not as easy as I thought it would be. Opening a new question probably wouldn't be a bad idea just to get some more eyes on it.